# What is mean by Action => 'ping' using send_action in Asterisk Manager Interface script?

Tags: asterisk, asteriskami

I have started to read about Asterisk::AMI module.
In that module if we want to send the action to the AMI server,we need to use the Action with action name using send_action method.
In that module they mentioned about Action => 'Ping' within send_action method.
Here what is the use of Action => 'Ping'.Can anyone explain me about it.

```
    send_action({   Action => 'Ping',
                    CALLBACK => \&method,
               });
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The Asterisk Manager Interface (AMI) allows a client program to connect to an Asterisk instance and issue commands or read events over a TCP/IP stream

Action: A packet sent by the connected client to Asterisk, requesting a particular Action be performed. There are a finite (but extendable) set of actions available to the client, determined by the modules presently loaded in the Asterisk engine. Only one action may be outstanding at a time

```
Action => Ping
```

gives Keep alive packet to be sent from the client to Astersik

Answer (score 1):

**Action**: Ping

**Synopsis**: Keepalive command

**Privilege**: <none>

**Description**: A 'Ping' action will elicit a 'Pong' response.  Used to keep the
  manager connection open.

**Variables**: NONE

You can get basic help for any Asterisk AMI command from within the Asterisk CLI
interface by typing

*manager show command **yourCommand***

You can see an entire list of supported commands by typing

*manager show commands*

BTW the shell command to get to the Asterisk CLI is

*asterisk -r*

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a just a keep alive.  Asterisk Manager Interface is known for being a little unreliable.  Astmanproxy is a good way to fix that.